# Is Salesforce SOQL GROUP BY case sensitive for different locales?

Tags: soql, group-by, locale, case-sensitive

Lets say I have records with values like 'TEST DATA' and 'test data' in some field. When I run SOQL (in Developer Console or from Apex) by user with EN locale, it arranges records with 'TEST DATA' and 'test data' values to one group, but when I run same query by user with non-English locale (or same user after switching locale to non-English), it separates records to different groups.

I tried several different non-English locales, like Spanish, German, Italian, and it works same.

The example of SOQL query is:

```
SELECT MyField__c MyField__c_2, GROUPING(MyField__c) grouping_MyField__c_2, SUM(Amount) SUM_Amount, count(Id) cnt 
FROM Opportunity 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(MyField__c) 
ORDER BY GROUPING(MyField__c) desc, MyField__c desc NULLS LAST
```

I think it should work same for any locales, and not sure why it's not. I know that in Salesforce SOQL sort order is determined by current user locale, but I observe same behavior for group by also, and don't know if this is correct behavior or not.

Comment: What happens if you use `COUNT_DISTINCT(MyField__c)` instead of `COUNT(Id)`? 

Comment: Results are same.

Comment: I've reached out to the [Salesforce Docs team on twitter](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/1144430844032909313). Often they are able to provide further clarification in scenarios like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Knowledge Article - [In the SOQL, GROUP BY is not case sensitive when User Locale is set to 'English'.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349474&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) states:

> **Description**
> If the User Locale is set to 'English', the GROUP BY in the SOQL behaves as case insensitive but for other user locales, it behaves as case sensitive.
>
> **Resolution**
> This is working as designed behavior when using current database.

Via [Anil on twitter](https://twitter.com/Anilysing/status/1152227236100988929).